How to handle loading in React Provider
I have concern about is it good idea adding Loading component in Provider?
I have NotificationsProvider below with the function to fetch data in it
I want consumers of this Provider, when they notifications it will be sure the notifications will exist so we don't need to check it every place or we don't need to use notificationsnotifications?... in consumers
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const NotificationsContext = createContext();

export const NotificationsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // Initialize as true

  // Simulate fetching data (replace with actual API call)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataFromBackend().then((data) => {
      setNotifications(data);
      setIsLoading(false); // Data fetched, set isLoading to false
    });
  }, []);

  // Other context logic...



  return isLoading? <Loading/> || (
    <NotificationsContext.Provider value={{ notifications }}>
      {children}
    </NotificationsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useNotifications = () => useContext(NotificationsContext);
```js

I try to return `<Loading/>` when `isLoading` is true. But I'm not sure it's right way to do.
I do some research but couldn't find the answer

